# C# make parent panel handle all event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, panel, parent

I was on my way to create a custom Progress Bar when I hit this problem [WinForm]

```
**The Structure:**
 -panel 
   -> panel
  so I have panel which inside the panel, there another panel.
```

> ```
> **The Goals:**
> -I want to use my parent panel as all event handler, 
>  while make the child panel have no event at all.
> ```

```
**The Problem:**
- when I press my mouse inside the child panel. the event in parent wont called.
  explanation : -> I still wanted to call parent panel mouse down 
  even if I click on top of my child panel.
```

Comment: Bubbling Event, Routed Event, or something similar... am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the click event to fire on the parent Panel when the child panel is clicked.

I can think of 2 ways you can do this.

First way is to simply call the Click event handler method for Panel1 from inside the Panel2's Click event handler method:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Panel 1 clicked.");
}

private void panel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Probably a better way would be to register both click events to the 1 handler method:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Panel 1 clicked.");
}
```

Then from the Form Designer or manually register the event for the second panel:

```
this.panel2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.panel1_Click);
```

Comment: if I do just like that. then when I try to take the e.X / e.Y will give the child coordinate. and I want to get the parent X&Y coordinate. is that possible?

Comment: You could have a separate method to do what you want with the coordinates, and from the outer panel call it directly, but from the inner panel you would need to calculate them from the inner panel's coordinates and the position of the panel (panel.Top and panel.Left).